# Problem when using predict() with different number of rows in the datasets

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, prediction

I am trying to predict the variable "Mittelwert.von.BAGSOLD" in this dataset:

```
> str(evaluate)
 'data.frame':  38 obs. of  8 variables:
  $ Zeilenbeschriftungen  : chr  "V104000" "V113396" "V114530" "V114538" ...
  $ Mittelwert.von.YIELD  : num  58.6 70.1 61.7 61.2 62.7 ...
  $ Mittelwert.von.RM     : num  1.5 3.9 2.7 2.8 2.9 ...
  $ Mittelwert.von.BAGSOLD: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  $ CHECKYIELD            : num  0.0687 0.1443 0.1075 0.1204 0.1207 ...
  $ ELITEYIELD            : num  0.0933 0.2706 0.0739 0.0783 0.0827 ...
  $ CHECKRM               : num  0 0.1716 0.0575 0.0684 0.0907 ...
  $ ELITERM               : num  0 0.238 0.0482 0.0606 0.0874 ...
```

For this, I have created a model with training data:

```
> summary(sigfit4.1)

Call:
lm(formula = Mittelwert.von.BAGSOLD[1:33] ~ Mittelwert.von.YIELD[1:33] + 
    Mittelwert.von.RM[1:33] + I(Mittelwert.von.RM[1:33]^2) + 
    CHECKYIELD[1:33] + ELITEYIELD[1:33])

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-587705 -230267  -34595  188290 1031175 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                    172229     811218   0.212   0.8335  
Mittelwert.von.YIELD[1:33]      20184      14071   1.435   0.1629  
Mittelwert.von.RM[1:33]       -504961     504743  -1.000   0.3260  
I(Mittelwert.von.RM[1:33]^2)    89627      97688   0.917   0.3670  
CHECKYIELD[1:33]              6084094    3384477   1.798   0.0834 .
ELITEYIELD[1:33]             -5212476    2097812  -2.485   0.0195 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 342200 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4386,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3347 
F-statistic:  4.22 on 5 and 27 DF,  p-value: 0.005798
```

When I use the predict function, it gives me this:

```
> predict(sigfit4.1, evaluate)
    1         2         3         4         5         6 
 731637.9  449129.3  976552.2 1020964.9 1029174.9 1034898.2 
    7         8         9        10        11        12 
 917621.8  864538.9 1082519.9 1097058.9  988477.0  996947.2 
   13        14        15        16        17        18 
 859176.3  806050.6 1037852.4  505977.2  867236.8  867013.6 
   19        20        21        22        23        24 
 798397.0  839654.8  991860.7  743150.7  805299.0  772278.8 
   25        26        27        28        29        30 
 746185.6  669009.0  672425.3  236245.3  532174.5  471704.5 
   31        32        33 
1106502.1  925001.8  933865.8 
Warnmeldung:
'newdata' had 38 rows but variables found have 33 rows
```

How do I get the prediction data for all 38 rows?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is produced by the way you used the formula. Notice in your summary that your variables have names which ends with `[1:33]`. I think this is not your intention, since usually you want to use the names of the variables without indices.

Instead of that, for training time, use the specification with formula and data parameters. Like small made up example:

```
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100, 0, 2), x1=rnorm(100, 0, 10), x2=rnorm(100, 1, 1))
summary(df)

lm1 <- lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = df[1:33,])
summary(lm1)

predict(lm1, df[34:100,])
```

In your case it should be:

```
lm(formula = Mittelwert.von.BAGSOLD ~ Mittelwert.von.YIELD
+ Mittelwert.von.RM + I(Mittelwert.von.RM^2) 
+ CHECKYIELD + ELITEYIELD, data = sigfit4.1[1:33])
```